# Upload PSD/any photoshop file via HTML File Input not working

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, mime-types, photoshop

I am trying to upload a file using HTML File Input (). 
But even if I pass to it's accept property valid mimetypes for photoshop files e.g. `application/psd`/`application/photoshop`/`application/x-psd`/`image/psd`/`image/x-psd` etc. it doesn't recognize the type and doesn't show corresponding files in the explorer.

But then I try to use `All Files` and get the `File` right. But there is no `FileType` in it. It's showing `"" empty string` like this. For which I am failing to identify the file in the server.

I tried a lot to find a solution for this but failed. Am I missing something or HTML File Input doesn't support that? Or I'll have to do something else for that?

Is there any other way of getting around with that?

Comment: blast from the past: did you ever find a solution to this?
or you just switched to checking the filename that ends in .psd ?

Comment: Yes, I just checked the file extension manually, I couldn't find out any proper solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you can use file extensions inside the accept attribute like this `<input type="file" accept=".psd">`.
I checked the `files` property of the input element with the console debugger and it's correctly showing me all of the files' data.